# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in (non object)

Tags: php, mysql, class

I get this error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 25.
I have marked the line 25 that it's referring to; can someone please check and tell what's wrong? I tried all possible ways, but can't figure it out.

class db

```
class db {

public $connect;
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
private $dns="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=etrharam_db";
private $method=array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"set name utf8");

public function connection(){
    $connect= new PDO($this->dns,$this->username,$this->password,$this->method);
    return $connect;
}/*connection*/

public function Idu($query,$data){
    $pre=$this->connect->prepare($query);
    foreach($data as $index=>$val){
        $pre->bindValue($index+1,$val);
    }
    $pre->execute();
}/*idu*/    

public function Select($query,$data){
    $pre=$this->connect->prepare($query);
    foreach($data as $index=>$val){
        $pre->bindValue($index+1,$val);
    }
    $pre->execute();
    $res=$pre->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $res;
}/*select*/

}/*db*/
```

test.php

```
include ('oop.php');
$oop= new db;
$query="SELECT * FROM `newcoll_tbl` WHERE id=?";
$data=array('1');
$res=$oop->Select($query,$data);
print_r($res);
```

what is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: dump $connect variable  and see what in there

Comment: I think you forgot to call the function connection() to define your $connect variable.

Comment: also, after you get your connection working, and other issues in this code, please take time to read about **[the usefulness of PDO wrappers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/class-for-reducing-development-time/29394#29394)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$connect` is empty because it's never filled. Your function `connection` is never called, that's why your getting this error.

To fix this, you can do two things:

- Call `$oop->connection();`
- Change name of function `connection` to `__construct` so it runs automatically when calling `$oop= new db();`

I would recommend the second option

Comment: **I've done all this, but the PDOException (__construct) gives the error!! Thank you for solving my problem**